# Rear Derailleur won't move

Tags: derailleur

I've changed my chain, and now when I shift into lowest gear, the rear derailleur won't move back out, and the cable goes slack. Any  insight?

Comment: With such a few info you can't get a really answer. Good pictures will let us help you more. I can suggest that you added too small chain, and when it comes to lowest gear the chain pulling the derailleur too much until it stuck.

Comment: If you pull on the cable, does the derailleur shift? Most derailleurs go into the smallest cog without tension, so we need some more details.

Comment: Photos of the area might help, but my first guess is weak spring and/or dirty cables.  When did you last change out the inners and outers?  Are the visible cables shiny silver or dirty rust coloured?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a bike with a similar problem last weekend, but as other people have said, it's hard to know the correct answer without pictures and a better description.

In his case, the derailleur cage had somehow sprung past the stopper and the spring was fully unwound. The result was that the derailleur did not provide any chain tension.

Fixing it required:

1. Remove the chain
2. Rotate the cage against the spring and past the stopper, which was hard to get past
3. Put the chain back on.

After that it worked perfectly.